How can I generate the same unique ID in C# that .NET 9 Aspire appends to resource names?
When I deploy my .NET 9 Aspire application to Azure, a unique ID is added to the names of the resources. I would like to know how to replicate this ID generation process within my C# code in ASP.NET.
Here's the .NET 9 Aspire AppHost program.cs code:
var builder = DistributedApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var cosmos = builder.AddAzureCosmosDB("cosmos");

var apiService = builder.AddProject<Projects.AspireApp1_ApiService>("apiservice")
.WithReference(cosmos)
.WaitFor(cosmos);

builder.AddProject<Projects.AspireApp1_Web>("webfrontend")
.WithExternalHttpEndpoints()
.WithReference(apiService)
.WaitFor(apiService);

builder.Build().Run();

So when I deploy this to Microsoft Azure, it generates an unique short string that will be used to rename the resources created for this project for example "cosmos" will be "cosmos-l82fdez", "api" will be "api-l82fdez".

how are you deploying your application?

please provide more details

are you deploying to Azure Web apps or container apps?

Are you trying replicate this ID generation in ASP.Net core or framework?

is your aspire code creating a resource with unique id in azure portal?

It is possible, but probably not intended.
First the function that generates the whole name in 9:
public override BicepValue<string>? ResolveName(
    ProvisioningContext context,
    Resource resource,
    ResourceNameRequirements requirements)
{
    string prefix = SanitizeText(
        resource.ResourceName, requirements.ValidCharacters);

    string separator =
        requirements.ValidCharacters.HasFlag(ResourceNameCharacters.Hyphen) ? "-" :
        requirements.ValidCharacters.HasFlag(ResourceNameCharacters.Underscore) ? "_" :
        requirements.ValidCharacters.HasFlag(ResourceNameCharacters.Period) ? "." :
        "";

    BicepValue<string> suffix = GetUniqueSuffix(context, resource);

    return BicepFunction.Take(
        BicepFunction.Interpolate(
            $"{prefix}{separator}{suffix}"), requirements.MaxLength);
}

Code here
Then the hard part, that unique ID. That can be generated client side, but it's not "supported". There is a Powershell Module AzExpression which utilizes Azure.Deployments.Expression to generate unique ids.
Following should work with version 1.0.694 of Azure.Deployments.Expression
Azure.Deployments.Expression.Expressions.FunctionArgument[] arguments = [new Azure.Deployments.Expression.Expressions.FunctionArgument("cosmos")];
var context = new Azure.Deployments.Expression.Expressions.ExpressionEvaluationContext();
var result = Azure.Deployments.Expression.Expressions.ExpressionBuiltInFunctions.Functions.EvaluateFunction("uniqueString", arguments, context, null, null);
Console.WriteLine(result);

Note that to get the same id it might also require subscription id, tenant id and/or resource group id as well, so this probably doesn't work out of the box.
